# AnimatedVectorDrawable as map marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use `animatedVectorDrawable` as the map marker in Android. Is there a way to do this.
What i tried is, I use `BitmapDescriptorFactory` class to convert `VectorDrawable` to bitmap and it work fine , but when i go to convert `AnimatedVectorDrawable` it show nothing on map

*Below code what i tried so far*

```
   .
   .
   .
    MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions();
    marker1.icon( getBitmapDescriptor(R.drawable.setpickuplocationdrawable));
    marker1.position(pickuplatlng);
    marker1.title("Marker at place1");
    googleMap.addMarker(marker1);
  }




private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptor(int id) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AnimatedVectorDrawable vectorDrawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(id);

        int h = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int w = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);

        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);

    } else {
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: no, you cannot do that

Comment: any other way to do that is'nt it

Comment: sorry, no, no other way

Comment: Confirmed, Cannot use regular `View` animation for Map components. The walkaround is to run a `ValueAnimator`, update the component's properties like alpha, radius or color continuously

Comment: i understand thanks for your answers

Comment: Hi @BasitRaza can you show how to use the valueAnimator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. In order to add an image to map as marker, you will need a bitmap (png preferable).
What you can do is convert the vector to a bitmap and try again.